# Bootstrap responsive inside iFrame

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

We have a site built with Angular/bootstrap.

This site should be configured inside of an Iframe of another domain.

my doubt is Should i write a resize script to properly scroll inside iFrame or since my app is designed using Bootstrap will it auomatically behave responsive according to parent domain iFrame size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bootstrap will take care of the responsiveness itself, but the only condition is, you follow the row and column structure properly.

Answer (score 0):

It depends whether you want the iframe to be a fixed height and have a vertical scrollbar or if you want the iframe to have a height that changes dynamically with your embedded page.

If it's the former you don't need to do anything, Bootstrap has the widths covered.

If you want the iframe height to change depending on the height of your embedded page (which will change with the responsive design), you need JS to resize the iframe.

For example

```
var iframeResize = function() {
    var iFrameID = document.getElementById('myIframe');
    if(iFrameID) {
        iFrameID.height = iFrameID.contentWindow.document.body.offsetHeight + "px";
    }
}

$(function() {
    $(window).resize(iframeResize);
});
```